# Error Recalling Data in GUI For Loop

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, for-loop

I have a GUI callback that includes a for loop but compared to running the same code in a script, the data/variable being retrieved within the loop after the loop ends is not being recognized and instead MATLAB says that the variable is undefined. The script runs fine with the same inputs. I am well aware that scripts and functions have different workspaces, but does this mean that the recent data in a function after ending a loop is forgotten?
The callback belongs to a push button while the data I am handling in that callback is symbolic.
I would like to know what is causing this problem

Comment: if you could provide a [mcve], it would be much easier for ppl to help you

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between functions and scripts.
functions have their local variables. These variables are defined within the scope of that function only. Inside of a function is isolated from the caller scope. The only way to exchange data is input and output parameters of the function.
When the flow of program reaches to a function, all variables are stored in stack, and the execution of function starts without any variables except the input parameter. On the exit from function, all local variable defined in the function are deleted, and the stored variable on the stack will be returned back to the scope.
To circumvent this mechanism, you can use

1. global variables
2. assignin and evalin functions

But this is not considered as a procedural programming.